# How to obtain AUC using leave-one-out cross-validation in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation, roc, glmnet

I have a matrix (x) containing 100 samples (rows) and 10000 independent features (columns). The observations are binary, either the sample is good or bad {0,1} (stored in vector y). I want to perform leave one out cross-validation and determine the Area Under Curve (AUC) for each feature separately (something like colAUC from CAtools package). I tried to use glmnet, but it didn't work. As it is said in manual, I tried to set the nfold parameter to be equal to the number of observations (100).

```
>result=cv.glmnet(x,y,nfolds=100,type.measure="auc",family="binomial")
```

And I'm getting these warnings:

```
>"Warning messages:
1: Too few (< 10) observations per fold for type.measure='auc' in   
cv.lognet; changed to type.measure='deviance'. Alternatively, use smaller  
value for nfolds 
2: Option grouped=FALSE enforced in cv.glmnet, since < 3 observations per  
fold"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? And is there any other way or R package to obtain LOO-balanced AUC values for each of the features?

I'll really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When you do a LOO-CV, you have a test set with only 1 sample in it, and you can of course not build an AUC with that. However, you can loop and store the predictions at each step:

```
k <- dim(x)[1]
predictions <- c()
for (i in 1:k) {
  model <- glmnet(x[-i,], y[-i], family="binomial")
  predictions <- c(predictions, predict(model, newx=x[i,]))
}
```

So that in the end you can make a ROC curve, for example:

```
library(pROC)
roc(y, predictions)
```